# Poner coordenadas como variables para Google maps

Tags: javascript, variables, google-maps-v3

Necesito cambiar los numeros de las coordenadas por variables.

```
function initMap() {
  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    }
```

Hago así y no me funciona:

```
function initMap() {
  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: var1,
      lng: var2
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes declarar e inicializar las variables que vas a utilizar.

Por ejemplo, podrías recibirlas como parámetros de la función:

```js
function initMap(pLatitud, pLongitud) {
  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: pLatitud,
      lng: pLongitud
    }
  }
  console.log(mapOptions);
}
    
    
initMap(10.2, -11.256);
```

O simplemente declararlas e inicializarlas dentro de la misma:

```js
function initMap(pLatitud, pLongitud) {
  const latitud = 10.2312;
  const longitud = -12.1423;
  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {
      lat: latitud,
      lng: longitud
    }
  }
  console.log(mapOptions);
}
    
    
initMap();
```

Comment: Las coordenadas me vienen por PHP de otra página y no logro que me funcione.

Comment: @XavierBisbeSerra por favor añade esa información  a la pregunta.

Comment: @Xavier, considero que he respondido a la pregunta que has hecho. Si hay información que has omitido, bueno, que puedo decir, debieras considerar aceptar esta respuesta y realizar otra pregunta, o quizás editar tu pregunta y hacer que, con eso, mi respuesta quede obsoleta y sea inválida. Por favor, antes de continuar, lee [ask] y trata siempre de incluir los detalles relevantes a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Ahora ya me funciona, gracias.
Este es el código.

```
<script>
var posicio = "<?php echo $lloc; ?>"; 

    function initMap(platitud, plongitud) {
    
    var lati_long=posicio.split(","); 
    var platitud=(lati_long[0]);
    var plongitud=(lati_long[1]);
    var coords = {lat: platitud, lng: plongitud};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        zoomControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false, 
        center:new google.maps.LatLng(platitud,plongitud),
          });

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(platitud,plongitud),
        icon: {
        url: '../icones/marcador.png',
        scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(52, 80), 
    }
      });
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta? o es una ampliación de tu pregunta? Si es el primer caso, deberías explicar que modificaciones hiciste para solucionar el problema. Si es el segundo, la zona de respuestas no es la adecuada. Pulsa el boton editar en tu pregunta y añada ahi toda la información que consideres relevante para tu pregunta.